# Lunar Lobster giving Not Responding notices

Tags: firefox, thunderbird

I have upgraded Ubuntu from Jellyfish to Lunar Lobster on Toshiba Satellite laptop.
Now, on opening with Firefox, Thunderbird or even IsleRiot - after the initial screen, I get #whatever_selected# Not Responding, Force Quit or Wait.

It follows the same pattern like opening another window, a right click, click a link or try to play a card etc.,I get the Not Responding notice.
Also it seems that the camera, speakers are not present.
Any suggestions of what might be the cause, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Are you sure your upgrade was successful? There is no supported direct upgrade path. so it's unclear what you did.

Comment: 1. I followed Ubuntu's guide to upgrade (and did it by GUI).
2. However I did have some features 'misbehaving' before the upgrade to Lunar Lobster.
 Perhaps this was the cause of "Not Responding" after upgrade.
3. I was going to try to revert the kernel but eventually after difficulty with that, it was more expedient to downgrade to Jammy Jellyfish using https://www.fosslinux.com/122699/how-to-safely-downgrade-your-ubuntu-installation.htm. Working well again!